# How to create a conditional infinite if loop for parsing XML into a pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, xml, pandas, dataframe, elementtree

I am trying to convert an xml file into dataframes to add into a dictionary. Below is the structure

```
<id =123>
      <table_group>
        <table_1>
          <col_heading1>value1</col_heading1>
          <col_heading2>value2</col_heading2>
          <col_heading3>value3</col_heading3>
        </table_1>
        <table_2>
          <col_heading1> value1 </col_heading1>
          <col_heading2> value2 </col_heading2>
          <col_heading3>
              <sub_col_heading1> value3 </sub_col_heading1>
          </col_heading3>
        </table_2>
      </table_group>
</id>
<id =124>
      <table_group>
        <table_1>
          <col_heading1>value1</col_heading1>
          <col_heading2>value2</col_heading2>
          <col_heading3>value3</col_heading3>
        </table_1>
        <table_2>
          <col_heading1> value1 </col_heading1>
          <col_heading2> value2 </col_heading2>
          <col_heading3>
              <sub_col_heading1> value3 </sub_col_heading1>
          </col_heading3>
        </table_2>
      </table_group>
</id>
```

This is a heavy file with multiple tables with multiple columns, within multiple table groups for multiple ids.

I want to create a loop that is flexible for each table to create a dataframe for each table, adding each id and their respective values for that table. However, some tables have more than one level or child for where their value should be. See table_2, col_heading3. This node has a child, sub_col_heading1. I created a code that works if the expected col_heading only has one level extra, but i'm noticing some tables have more than one level.

This code works for one table, ideally if it were more flexible I can loop through multiple tables, however each one has a different structure and their children might have more than one level.

```
import pandas as pd
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
tree = ET.parse('xml')
root = tree.getroot()
dffx = pd.DataFrame() #empty dataframe to be filled with parsed XML data for one table

for ids in range(len(root[1].getchildren())): #loops for all the ids in the xml file, about 12000 total.

    data =[] 
    cols = [] #should be the column heading
    values = [] #holds the values for the respective col_heading, to be zipped into a dictionary
    dff1 = pd.DataFrame(data) #create a temp dataframe
    cols.append('InstrumentId') #adds the ID into the dataframe, as the table does not include it
    values = [str(root[1][ids].attrib)[8:-2]] #isolates the id number as it is an attrib
    for i in root[1][ids][0][0].getchildren():#ideally this would be looped as for table root[1][ids][0][table].getchildren(), but root[1][ids][table_group][table2].getchildren() is for one table right now.
        if i.text == '\n            ': # .text should be the value, if i does not have value that means it needs to go down another level
            for x in i.getchildren(): #next level under i, if there is another level then x.text = \n and needs to go down another level, for the same if logic 
                cols.append(x.tag) #grab field name 
                values.append(x.text) #grab value
                cols.append(i.tag) #grab parent field name
                values.append(x.tag) #make parent value = child field name, this logic should apply the more levels down, adding the parent.tag as the child value if another level needs to be added
        else:
            cols.append(i.tag) # if only one level then field name 
            values.append(i.text) #value

    data.append(dict(zip(cols,values)))
    dff1 = dff1.append(data, ignore_index= False)
    dffx= dffx.append(dff1)
```

The nested if statement is what I want to make an infinite conditional loop. If the first level does not have a text value, but has children, get children values and make the parent value the child name, if the child does not have values but has grandchildren get the grandchildren values, make the child value the grandchild name etc etc.

Comment: Start by uploading a well formed xml. The current one is invalid

Comment: As an aside, repeatedly appending to a DataFrame in a loop is generally a bad idea. It's best to add the data to an intermediate data structure (like a list), and construct the entire DataFrame at once.